# What subjects should I study to learn about eigenfunctions? What good textbooks would you recommend for learning the subject?

Tags: reference-request, eigenfunctions

I googled eigenfunction and look it up in wikipedia, but still I do not know where I should start to learn the subject. I have two questions, and allow me to repeat the title of this question.

1. What subjects should I study to learn about eigenfunctions?
2. What good textbooks would you recommend for learning the subject?

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "learn about eigenfunctions"? It isn't really the name of a subject. Do you want to learn operator theory / functional analysis? Spectral theory?

Comment: Because I am not clear about where I should start, the question is not clear. Thank you for any comments, though.

Comment: Why do you need to learn about eigenfunction? For Quantum Mechanics?

Comment: I want to read and understand a paper that mentioned eigenfunctions. Because it seems to be too advanced, I did not understand details of the paper. A paper in theoretical population genetics.

Comment: To answer this question properly, we need to know more about you and why you want to learn this. How much mathematics have you seen/what is your background? Why do you want to learn about these things?

Comment: @SangcheolChoi What subject are you studying?

Comment: I did take only second-year college level mathematics such as calculus, linear algebra, real analysis, and a little bit of differential equations. I am not sure whether these are second-year or first-year level of math. The paper that I want to understand is available at http://www.genetics.org/content/190/3/1117.full.pdf

Comment: I thought that there is some kind of subject title just like linear algebra if I want to learn about matrix operation or linear regression. So, it seems like that that there is no subject title that deals with eigenfunctions. Until now, I got impression that the subject of differential equations might be related with eigenfunctions.

Comment: Getting to the point where you are comfortable with the theory behind what's going on in that paper will take a while, but the field you are looking for is functional analysis.  The result being used here (at least what I saw when I glanced at the paper) is the spectral theorem for self adjoint operators.

For a reference, look at Reed Simon Modern Methods in Mathematical Physics I.  It's the standard reference.

Comment: Thank you, Chris and other helpers as well. I see that I might not be able to understand the detail of the paper, but I want to take some of spare time to learn as much as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a very good answer to your question, but based on the article it looks like you might actually want to study partial differential equations. Eigenfunction expansion is a nice technique to help understand these equations, in exactly the same way eigenvectors let us understand linear transformations (some PDEs actually are just linear transformation, in a sense).

Since you want to understand PDE involved in population dynamics, I would suggest you look at a more applied book on PDEs. I unfortunately don't know any. A quick search for "Applied PDE Book" gave this as the number one on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Partial-Differential-Equations-Edition/dp/0130652431](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130652431)

This book appears to cover the topics you need to understand the paper, based on a very casual glance of both the paper and the contents of the book. I don't know the level of difficulty of the text, so be prepared to review or learn new things in linear algebra or analysis.

Many of the comments suggest learning functional analysis. I initially wanted to recommend this, but I'm afraid that if you go out and pick up a typical book on functional analysis, it will be too abstract and difficult to transfer to your paper. A sufficiently advanced PDE book should include the techniques from functional analysis you need.

Comment: Your answer does make sense to me. Although my question is neither good nor clear, I think that Zach's answer seems to be one that I have been looking for. Thank you again.